# Expected: OBJECT_START but got ARRAY_START at [16]

Tags: json, ubuntu, solr

How to add multiple JSON documents through the Solr Admin Documents page?

I tried with json:

```
[ 
{ 
   "id" : "001", 
   "name" : "Ram", 
   "age" : 53, 
   "Designation" : "Manager", 
   "Location" : "Hyderabad", 
}, 
{ 
   "id" : "002", 
   "name" : "Robert", 
   "age" : 43, 
   "Designation" : "SR.Programmer", 
   "Location" : "Chennai", 
}, 
{ 
   "id" : "003", 
   "name" : "Rahim", 
   "age" : 25, 
   "Designation" : "JR.Programmer", 
   "Location" : "Delhi", 
} 
]
```

After click Submit Document, it returns errors:

> Status: error
>   Error: Bad Request
>    "msg": "Expected: OBJECT_START but got ARRAY_START at [16]",
>       "code": 400

Answer (score 9):

Remove the [ ] bracket, this works for me.

```
{ 
      "id" : "001", 
      "name" : "Ram", 
      "age" : 53, 
      "Designation" : "Manager", 
      "Location" : "Hyderabad" 
   }, 
   { 
      "id" : "002", 
      "name" : "Robert", 
      "age" : 43, 
      "Designation" : "SR.Programmer", 
      "Location" : "Chennai"
   }, 
   { 
      "id" : "003", 
      "name" : "Rahim", 
      "age" : 25, 
      "Designation" : "JR.Programmer", 
      "Location" : "Delhi" 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove , before } symbol like follows

```
[ 
   { 
      "id" : "001", 
      "name" : "Ram", 
      "age" : 53, 
      "Designation" : "Manager", 
      "Location" : "Hyderabad" 
   }, 
   { 
      "id" : "002", 
      "name" : "Robert", 
      "age" : 43, 
      "Designation" : "SR.Programmer", 
      "Location" : "Chennai"
   }, 
   { 
      "id" : "003", 
      "name" : "Rahim", 
      "age" : 25, 
      "Designation" : "JR.Programmer", 
      "Location" : "Delhi" 
   } 
]
```

You can check json format in this link also https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: I just try and it still returns same errors Bad Request with msg: Expected: OBJECT_START but got ARRAY_START at [16]

Comment: try to use { instead of [ and  } instead of ]

Comment: It we use { instead of [ and } instead of ] It returns JSON Parse Error.

Btw, I still post above json through terminal by syntax
./post -c name_core file_include_json_content.json

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the square braces and , at the end  from Hyderabad, Chennai and Delhi.
It will work

Answer (score 0):

select "JSON" from the pulldown... this accepts only a single JSON document to be added, because it wraps it in tags like so...

```
{
    "add": {
         "doc": YOUR_TEXT_AREA_INPUT, 
         "boost": BOOST_FORM_INPUT, 
         "overwrite": CHECKBOX_INPUT, 
         "commitWithin": COMMIT_WITHIN_FORM_INPUT
     }
}
```

You should be choose "Solr Command (raw XML or JSON)",like this:

```
{
    "add":{
        "doc":{
            "product_catalog_name": "123",
            "product_price": 80,
            "product_name": "a",
            "id": "33998",
            "product_picture": "2014032417271233.png"
        }
    },
    "add":{
        "doc":{
            "product_catalog_name": "123",
            "product_price": 100,
            "product_name": "b",
            "id": "33999",
            "product_picture": "2014032417271233.png"
        }
    }
}
```